# Read data off a DHT 11 sensor using Node Red?

Tags: node-red

I am currently trying out Node-Red and I have a question regarding the use of the DHT11 sensor where I am able to get data to show via debug and is able to extract said data to the gauge chart.

Now i am trying to get the same data but to display on a line chart but it is unable to extract the same data, as I was able to do so with the gauge chart with the "Value Format" tab.

May anyone correct me on what I am doing wrong or provide me a solution to my problem that would be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

[image: This is the overall flow of the chart]
[image: This is the property of the gauge]
[image: The function of the Temperature]
[image: The Gauge display, there are values in the line chart as we directly connected it to the DHT sensor it]

Comment: You haven't shown us how you've configured the line chart for the temperature.